# capturing multiple groups of characters from a single line

Tags: regex

I need a single line regex to cater for capturing 0 to multiple groups. The lines always begin with a single "{" then a digit, then a colon... ie in regex terms `{%d:` then keep on capturing until it hits the closing curly bracket `}`

Some example lines below:

```
{1:23842039423409} 
{2:JSHDF98343SSDSDASASDSASDSAD993}{1:JSHDF98343993}
{2:JSHDF98343993}{1:23842039423409}{1:BLHASD9293}
{2:{JSHDF98343993}{1:23842039423409}{1:BLHASD9293}
{4missing_colon_not_to_be_captured}
{missing_number_not_to_be_captured}{2:CAPTURE_THIS}
```

- Line 1 there should be 1 group captured,
- Line 2 there should be 2 groups captured,
- Line 3 there should be 3 groups captured,
- line 4 there should be 3 groups captured,
- line 5 nothing is captured,
- line 6 there is 1 group that is captured.

I have got something that almost works (kind of), by repeating the regex for multiple groups, but don't think this is the right way to go about this, but am struggling to understand how to make it work completely.

```
([{%d:][^}]*})([{%d:][^}]*})
```

The will capture groups where there are more than two things to capture on a line, but will ONLY capture the first 2 groups obviously ie the 2 groups in line 2, the first 2 groups in line 3 (but not the 3rd group), the first 2 groups in line 4 (but not the 3rd group), etc.

I have tried a few other variations with no success. Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Your item pattern must be `{\d:[^}]*}` or `{\d+:[^}]*}`. Then, you can't have an arbitrary number of capturing groups, their number is always fixed by the pattern. Thus, you either match all occurrences with `{\d+:[^}]*}` or add as many optional groups as you think necessary to support their max occurrence number with something like `({\d+:[^}]*})({\d+:[^}]*})?({\d+:[^}]*})?({\d+:[^}]*})?({\d+:[^}]*})?`

Comment: What language/tool are you using with your regex?

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor will try that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using a data prep tool called "Paxata" which implements javascript regex I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{\d:.+?}
```

See Description at https://regexr.com/4n0l1

Comment: This worked to fix the problem as described, however @TimBiegeleisen's comment actually fixed my issue `({\d+:[^}]*})({\d+:[^}]*})?({\d+:[^}]*})?({\d+:[^}]*})?`